# Bug: Can't vote for answer (or possibly, vote is not being shown)

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

When I view [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/sync-picasa-web-albums-option-not-there/5260#5260), the upvote and downvote buttons are not highlighted, which seems to indicate that I have not voted on it.  However, when I try to vote it doesn't let me, saying I last voted 23 hours ago.

I believe I **tried** to vote on this answer yesterday, but had already used all my votes for the day.  So my guess is that an answer's votes and the answers-I-have-voted-on are tracked distinctly, and the code is preventing my "extra" vote from being added to the answer's votes but not preventing it from being added to answers-I-have-voted-on.

**Edit:** As per Al's answer below, this is apparently by design but meant to be applied to a different situation.  What's the rationale for applying this to votes in excess of the daily limit?  (Seems like a tiny bit of laziness ...)

**Edit 2:** I was just able to upvote the answer linked above.  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We changed how you're able to [recast a vote from a neutral state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373).

Comment: Great, thanks for the info and for the change!

Answer (score 2):

I do know that if you vote on a post, then immediately retract your vote, you won't later be able to vote on it. This is apparently by design.

I expect this is the same situation, although you didn't retract your vote voluntarily, but were forced to by the vote limit.

You won't be able to vote on it until it's edited.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't experienced that but I'll experiment using this answer :P

Comment: The cutoff for locking in your vote is (I believe) 5 minutes.

Comment: Welp I have been cut off from voting on this answer, so that answers that.  Thanks Al.  Do you know what the rationale for this is?  Some balance between ease-of-coding and preventing someone's rep from being twiddled up and down indefinitely?

Comment: There are several discussions on http://meta.stackoverflow.com, but basically it's to prevent tactical downvoting. Downvote competing answers until your answer got voted up, then clearing downvotes.

Comment: Make sense.  Thanks

Comment: Whoa OK, I was just able to vote up this answer and the answer I linked above.  What the hell?

Comment: Was just changed today. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373

Comment: This must be a bug, if you reached your vote limit, you did not "retract" your vote (voluntarily or involuntarily); you never voted in the first place.

Comment: @Lie I think they just didn't bother to distinguish the cases.  In any case, the new change fixes the behaviour I saw.